# Как правильно вывести элементы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть массив: `[(3, 1), (2, 3), (4, 2)]`. На каждой итерации такой массив  собирается к определенной строке.
Нужно вывести его первые элементы. Только не `for i in range: print(i[0])`, чтобы не печатать по одному элементу, и не печатать по строке, например, `3, 2, 4`, а сджойнить эти строки со строкой и вне уже цикла вывести весь результат. Код:

```
for _ in range(количество строк):
    строка = input()

    ... что-то делаем со строкой

    for i in массив:
        print(i[0])
```

---

Мой код, который выводит не

```
1 2 3
2 2
6 4
```

а без новой строки     1 2 3 2 2 6 4

```
for _ in range(n):
    строка = input()

    for i, j in array:
        result = result.join(('', f'{i} '))

print(result)
```

Как нормально сджойнить строку, чтобы она сохранилась с переносом строки

---

*вывод 1 2 3\n2 2\n 6 4 тестовый, на каждой новой строке результат для введенной строки, то есть для каждой введенной строки формируется свой такой массив, поэтому они на новых строках, а сверху я привел пример одного массива для одной строки

Comment: вывод в вопросе не соответствует вашим же данным

Comment: @Эникейщик вы про какой вывод конкретно

Comment: как вы из `[(3, 1), (2, 3), (4, 2)]` получили   `1 2 3`?

Comment: Про любой. Откуда там 6, например?

Comment: @Эникейщик в самом начале я привел пример и массива, и результата для него. А позже я просто как пример вывода написал, он ни к чему не привязан, сейчас исправлю для ясности

Comment: Ну просто собирайте в цикле строку из первых элементов простой операцией +, и на забудьте про  пробелы

Comment: @Эникейщик строку собрать легко, только время будет квадратичное

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(massiw):
    return ' '.join([str(i[0]) for i in massiw])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]